# Multiple URL Formats per element type (Entries, Categories)

Tags: url, routes, slug

I suspect this boils down to a feature request, but I'll start here in case there are any other ideas.

Basically, I want to be able to define multiple URL formats for a single section or category group.

Here is the scenario:

- Section `gear` with URL format `gear/{slug}`
- Category group `productTypes` with URL format `gear/{slug}`, `{parent.uri}/{slug}`
- Section `reviews` with URL format `reviews/{slug}`.

What I want to do but can't, is define a *second* URL format for `productTypes`, with the format `reviews/{slug}`, and `{parent.uri}/{slug}`.

Similarly, I want to define a 2nd format for `gear`, of `reviews/{slug}`.

So I'd end up with:

- gear/gear-entry/
- gear/category/
- reviews/category/
- reviews/gear-entry/
- reviews/review-entry/

So I really need Craft to know about those additional formats to avoid crossover URLs.

Routing and assigning the `entry` and `category` variables is not a problem, I'm really just concerned with the slug/uri validation.

Answer (score 3):

So semantically, I don’t love the URL format you’re coming up with.  I’d like to see something like `/gear/{category}/{entry}`

This gives you a few benefits

- it’s semantically readable…
- it gives you natural breadcrumbs for the hierarchy of content
- it’s likely going to be better from an SEO perspective

Relevant feature request: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1189

Comment: Changing the URL altogether could certainly make things easier. Your suggestion could odd with multiple category assignments and nesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only worried about URL collisions, it looks like there's only a few places where your routes overlap:

- `gear/{slug}` could match a gear entry or a category.
- `reviews/{slug}` could match a category, gear entry, or review entry.

One easy way around this is to just just make some of these routes more specific. For example:

- `gear/{slug}` (gear entry)
- `gear/category/{slug}` (product type category)
- `reviews/category/{slug}` (product type category)
- `reviews/gear/{slug}` (gear entry)
- `reviews/{slug}` (review entry)

Note: "category" above is the literal string, not the category's slug. But if "category" is too verbose, possibly just `gear/cat/{slug}` or `gear/c/{slug}`.

Or...

If you wanted to alter your URL formats minimally from your original scheme, another option would be to setup `gear`, `productTypes`, and `reviews` to all use the same route of `reviews/{slug}`. Craft *will* use a section's Entry URL Format when saving an entry to check for duplicate slugs.

- `reviews/{slug}` (product type category)
- `reviews/{slug}` (gear entry)
- `reviews/{slug}` (review entry)

Then just add a "category" segment for gear to make sure `gear` entries don't clash with `productTypes` categories:

- `gear/{slug}` (gear entry)
- `gear/category/{slug}` (product type category)

Comment: It does check the full URI for duplicates against any URL formats it knows about. Which is great, and the feature I'm trying to leverage.

Comment: Yep, your "category" segment solution works, and is actually what I'm doing currently. It would be nice if there were a way to define both formats in Craft though, so that Craft itself knew about all your URLs. Feature request: http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/15678615-allow-multiple-url-formats-per-entry-type-entries

Comment: You're right, @TimKelty! Craft does check other section Entry URL formats. Craft rulez. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's a really nice feature! Would be even better given something like my FR, which would allow Craft to know about ALL of your URLs.